# Evaluating Expressions with Integer Exponents

Tags: proof-verification, exponentiation

Simplify the expression by writing as a single power and then evaluate for a=-1,b=-2 and c=3.

$$(b^{3}a^{4})^{2} \times (a^{3}c)^{3} \over ac^{3}$$

Here is what I did: 
$$\begin{align}\frac{(b^{3}a^{4})^{2} \times (a^{3}c)^{3}}{ac^{3}}
&=\frac{b^{6}a^{8} \times a^{9}c^{3}}{ac^{3}}\\
&=\frac{a^{17}b^{6}c^{3}}{ac^3}\\
&=a^{16}b^{6}\\
&=(-1)^{16}(-2)^{6}\\
&=(1)(64)\\
&= 64\end{align}$$

I have no answer key, is my answer correct?

Comment: Yes.  It is all well and fine.  You might try to get a bit more practice on typesetting however, there are a few minor things such as location of equals signs that can be fixed.  Otherwise good work.

Comment: Perfect,No mistake.I was doing this type of question last week.

Comment: If you were to ever want to check your answer,use the question and immediately subsitute.Check if high if the answers is the same.But of course,that's assuming you have a calculator